# Error when saving in jsfiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

I'm new to jsfiddle, and I'm having trouble saving my fiddles. Using the save or update function seems to only work erratically, and most of the time the latest version of my code doesn't appear anywhere in my dashboard. When I click "save" or "update", the console logs:

> Font from origin 'https://code.cdn.mozilla.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://jsfiddle.net' is therefore not allowed access.

I have no idea what that means, or if it's related. Basically, I just can't figure out how to use jsfiddle and haven't found an answer anywhere else. I'm a total novice so I appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Adam

Comment: Upvoting as I have the same problem - hoping this will generate more traffic to this question in case someone can help.